# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Query timeout expired while connection to Azure SQL Datawarehouse

Tags: sql, azure, azure-synapse

We have a .Net ASMX webservice hosted in IIS on an Azure VM. We are retriving some data from Azure SQL datawarehouse in the webservice. We have configured the following connection string in the web.config file.

add key="connectionString" value="Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=;Database=;Uid=;Pwd=;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=500; Pooling=true;Connection Timeout=10800"/

We tried to do a POC and made consecutive 200 calls to the webservice. In the webservice webmethod we are just opening the connections. However after just 55 to 60 calls we start getting exception : Connection timed out.

My question is why are we getting the connection timeout after just 55 calls when we have set the Max Pool Size value to 500 in connections string.
Is there any other setting I need to change to make it work for atleast 500 connections?

Azure SQL Datawarehouse is Gen2: DW1000c